# wireshark is telling my that the source ip is my router ip

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireshark

I am new on Wireshark and having a trouble with capturing the packages. my problem is that Wireshark is capturing the packages until the router like if I ping to google.com he is showing me the source IP is 192.168.0.1 which my router IP. what can I do to solve this problem? I was searching on the internet for 3 days and couldn't find anything to help me solve this problem.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQvHX.png)

[Here is a screenshot of  ip addr show; iptables -vnL; iptables -t mangle -vnL; iptables -t nat -vnL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gyBV.png)

Comment: Why not start off describing your network setup, the device you are capturing the traffic on, and the IP addresses of each machine.  Also, the firewall rules and routing rules for the box you are running wireshark on could be useful if there is some policy routing / NAT going on.

Comment: What do you mean? im using kali linux, i dont have any special rules or ny thing else. i have no any other devices working on my network except my computer. as i saw in youtube they just install it and starting work on it...... i dont know if i answered your question correctly....

Comment: I don't use Kali Linux, but I assume the following will work - please add it to your post - "ip addr show; iptables -vnL; iptables -t mangle -vnL; iptables -t nat -vnL" - This will how the list of interfaces on your system, and then some IPTables rules which could give us some hints.   Is the Kali box acting as a desktop, router or something else - ie how does it fit in to the data flow?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Wireshark probably captured several packages. The one that has 192.168.0.1 as it's source IP could be the DNS answer from your router. If your PC wants to ping a server it will send a DNS request to the router to ask for the IP address of that server.

Comment: @davidgo my kali is a desktop

Comment: @SpiderPig i have uploded a screenshot

Comment: It says "DNS" in the protocol column. So those are all DNS queries. If you want to see the ping packets, sort the protocol column and look for ICMP.

Comment: @SpiderPig well that is not my problem or my target, what I want is to locate an IP address from a people while chatting with them or playing with them

Comment: Sorry, but you can't do that. If you chat or play with other people there is always a server involved that acts as a middle man. So Wireshark will only show you the IP address of that server but not the addresses of the other players since there are never any packages exchanged directly between you and them. Everything goes through the server. However you could trick someone into clicking a link that will allow you to see their IP. e.g. with this site: http://whatstheirip.com/ or this: https://grabify.link/

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I believe it is because of how you dns is configured. I believe that your /etc/resolv.conf is populated with your router as the dns server. Most likely your router is forwarding the dns request to your isp or a 3rd party dns server such as google on their behalf.

The source ip address is showing up as your router because the router is forwarding the dns request to the dns servers specified for your router and it is returning the results of the dns request back to you.

To confirm could you look and see if other protocols are showing the same issue.

Comment: and how can i solve this? what i need to do to get it work as i want?

and i don't have a etc/resolv.conf !! i dont know why

Comment: Your router is most likely handing out its DNS servers to the computer via DHCP.

Comment: @AssadRajab dns taffic will always show the remote as the dns server. in your case the dns server is your router. to set your dns server to another external dns server you could specify it in your resolv.conf simply edit your /etc/resolv.conf and specify a different nameserver in there. The contents should look like "nameserver 8.8.8.8" for example to use googles public dns. What you showed in your screenshot is what should be shown when strictly viewing dns traffic